# How do I encrypt only selected values of a JSON payload using a public key in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, public-key-encryption

sample payload:

```
"object": {
    "a": "bau bau",
    "c": "boo boo",
    "e": "mrau mrau"
  },
```

encrypted payload:

```
"object": {
    "a": "kjdfhsijry874rhevfbwe",
    "c": "boo boo",
    "e": "vcsafsdkhdlksfhj23273"
  },
```

I have create the following script but getting an error even though I am passing string.
**ERROR:** **TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.**

```
    const crypto = require('crypto');
    const path = require('path');
    const fs = require('fs');

    const payload = require('./payload.json');
    console.log("original:", payload);

    const encrypted = encryptedJSON(payload, './public.pem', ["a", "e"]);
    console.log("encrypted:", encrypted);

    function encryptedJSON(obj, key, propertiesToEncrypt) {
        let result = { ...obj }; // Clone the object.
        const publicKey = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(key), "utf8");
        for(let property of propertiesToEncrypt) {
            result[property] = crypto.publicEncrypt({ key: publicKey }, Buffer.from(obj[property], "utf8")).toString("base64");
        }
        return result;
}
```

Comment: And, if you `console.log(obj)` right before that line?  It isn't clear from your question what's actually in these variables.  You say `"object": {}` implying that there's an outer object with one key called `object` within it, which would certainly break things.

Comment: Your code looks correct - I copied and ran it locally and it worked. I'm using node v12.14.0 on MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code *is* correct for this format of `payload.json`:

```
{
  "a": "bau bau",
  "c": "boo boo",
  "e": "mrau mrau"
}
```

But will fail for this one:

```
{
  "object": {
    "a": "bau bau",
    "c": "boo boo",
    "e": "mrau mrau"
  }
}
```

Because it's trying to encrypt the top-level property "a" that doesn't exist (the only property is "object").
If your payload follow the latter format, you can tweak your code like this:

```js
const encrypted = encryptedJSON(payload.object, './public.pem', ["a", "e"]);
```